# How can I read lines from a text file letter by letter?

Tags: c#

I have an ASCII text file.  I want to read the file, line by line, divide it by positions, and save every value to a database, using C#. How might I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "divide by positions"?

Comment: Can you please show an example of your text file and elaborate on what you want to do exactly. Are the values in the file delimited with a character and you want to split every line and get those values out?

Comment: Which part?  Opening a text file and reading it?  Splitting it into chunks?  Persisting it to the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: this is  the one line "188888888000000001106400000008676240031117757 cruhbr ‰’—00000000126000000000000000000041200000000000504000000000000000000  "How I can read the 10 first and then 5 more anve it?

Comment: jog, I sense that you know what you want, but you're not communicating your request well. Can you perhaps explain it to someone nearby, a coworker maybe, who can then write a new question for you?

Comment: edit your question to include this information

Comment: This was not really clear when reading your question, but perhaps you should play around a bit with the code i posted below. It gives you the lines in the file, and from there on you can take them further apart and do something with the strings / chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file")` is the easiest way to get an array with each line of the file, but will load the whole thing into memory so might not be good for big files.

so something like

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")) {
    var phoneNumber = line.Substring(0, 10); //get first 10 chars
    var zipCode = line.Substring(10, 5); //get next 5 chars
    ... etc
    ... store to DB.
}
```

or alternatively in LINQ syntax, you could do

```
var data = from line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
           select new {Phone=line.Substring(0,10), Zip=line.Substring(10,5), ...};
foreach(var record in data) { 
    .. store to DB 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx):

```
using (var input = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(inputFileName), Encoding.ASCII))
{
  string line;
  while((line = input.ReadLine()) != null) // or read data other way you want
  {
    //Do something here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone, I know how to read .I sent a line has 10 data, the first from 0-7, the second from 8-12, and so to the end. I asked how I cut it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need something like this?

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
                for(int i = 0; i < line.Length;  i++){
                     //do something with  line[i]  
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Divide the line into chunks like this:

`    string chunk;
    int pos = 0;
    
    // inside the loop of Alex or tysHTTP
    chunk = line.Substring(pos, 10);
    pos += 10;
    // Do something with chunk
    
    chunk = line.Substring(pos, 5);
    pos += 5;
    // Do something with chunk`